# How do I playback a DVD in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, dvd

How do I playback a DVD in Ubuntu 17.10? I have so far:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

There used to be something called Fluendo in the Ubuntu repository but it doesn't appear to be there any more. Am I the only person left using Ubuntu?

I followed advice given in various other question on Ask Ubuntu and on the Ubuntu man pages https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs but was still unable to play DVDs.

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg fixed it. Thanks to myself and for future reference for myself...

Comment: vlc will play DVDs. `libdvdcss2`is also required for playing manufactured DVDs if it wasn't installed with `libdvd-pkg`

Comment: go ahead and post it as an answer so that someone else doing a search will see that the question was answered. Also someone quickly searching for answers may not read comments

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

fixed it.

Thanks to myself and for future reference if only for myself...

Comment: What a bizarre set of rules and regulations on this website. Surely it would be easier to maintain an accurate Ubuntu operation manual.

Answer (score 0):

install libs and codecs:

```
sudo apt install libdvdcss2 libdvdread4 libdvdnav4
```

and now you can play DVDs with `vlcplayer` and etc

Comment: These appear to be already installed - I don't know if they were installed as a result of what I installed, as detailed above, or as a result of something else.